# Why are certain letters on emulator virtual keypad showing numbers in Android EditText with inputtype as "number"?

Tags: android, emulation, android-edittext, numeric

I have an EditText widget in my Android application with *inputtype=number*.  It does restrict character to entry by number.  However, when I type certain alphabetic keys on the emulator's keypad (not all of them) I see numbers appear in the edit box.  For example, typing an "F" puts a "6" in the edit box, "D" puts a "5", etc.  Why is this happening?

-- roschler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It emulates the portrait keyboards that can be used to dial numbers also. Nothing wrong with your particular widget :)

Comment: Ah, I have the same thing happening, and it's a **very important** issue.  I'm capturing the keystrokes via onKey(View, KeyEvent), and the KeyEvent is NOT the same as the number.  I now have to handle twice as many events (twenty, instead of just ten).  And furthermore, as different phone implement this differently, I no longer have a consistent way to handle these events across phones.

Answer (score 2):

I've seen two things happen, depending if you're on the emulator or on the phone, and depending on the SDK version:

- The full keyboard appears (older SDKs). The behavior is exactly what you said: you can only type numbers, but certain characters can also be typed, and are translated to numbers. That behavior is explained by what Aleadam said.
- The soft phone keypad (mostly on modern SDKs and phones, as far as I've seen). The typical phone keypad appears... "2ABC", "3CDE" and so on...

On both situations, you will see that, in fact, only numbers can be entered, which is what we want. As an example, in preference screen, you can perfectly cast the `Object newValue` into a Integer and you won't have any problems.

I do that all the time, don't worry!

Answer (score 1):

If you enable that tag the emulator keyboard works like a T9.

ABC will be 2
DEF will be 3
etc.

It's normal, it's not a bug!